# Student Subject and Course Completion

Tags: desire2learn

Would someone be able to direct me to the correct API that I could use to mark a Student Subject and Course to ‘Complete’?

I found out ‘Grade.CourseCompletion’ API could serve the purpose, but not sure if that's correct understanding.

Also, where could I find below highlighted fields and how I can change their value?

```
"OrgUnitId": <number:D2LID>,
**"CompletionId": <number:D2LID>,**
"UserId": <number:D2LID>,
**"CompletedDate": <string:UTCDateTime>,**
"ExpiryDate": <string:UTCDateTime>|null
```

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a `CompletionId`; it's an entity identifier for the completion record that gets created by Brightspace when the completion record gets created. (I believe you could, however, delete a completion record and create a new one.)

You use the POST and PUT routes [for course completion](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html?highlight=completion#id4) to create new (or update existing) course completion records. The JSON structure you provide when you do a create or update operation allows you to specify a `CompletedDate`.

I would also point out that D2L has a [developer-specific community](https://community.brightspace.com/s/group/0F9610000001mZ1CAI/developers) to support clients and partners and you may find that answers to your questions are more timely there.

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Hagg..keen to know how does the completion record gets created? I mean what are the triggers to create a completion record? and Once it's created can i seen Completion Date, status etc. on the front end?